# PHP Qty distribution with max value

Tags: php, arrays, calculation, knapsack-problem, bin-packing

I've been struggle on this problem over than 2 weeks, I've data like below :
Someone told me it's should knapsack or anything, but I don't know how to do.

**Master Category**

| Category | Qty per Box |
| --- | --- |
| P | 12 |
| V | 8 |

**Order Transaction**

| Customer | Category | Order Qty | Qty Box |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| N1 | P | 40 | 12 |
| N2 | P | 8 | 12 |
| E1 | V | 40 | 8 |

**Expected result**

| Customer | Category | Order Qty | Qty Box | Pack Qty | Box ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| N1 | P | 40 | 12 | 12 | Box 1 |
| N1 | P | 40 | 12 | 12 | Box 2 |
| N1 | P | 40 | 12 | 12 | Box 3 |
| N1 | P | 40 | 12 | 5 | Box 4 |
| N2 | P | 8 | 12 | 7 | Box 4 |
| N2 | P | 8 | 12 | 1 | Box 5 |
| E1 | V | 40 | 8 | 8 | Box 6 |
| E1 | V | 40 | 8 | 8 | Box 7 |
| E1 | V | 40 | 8 | 8 | Box 8 |
| E1 | V | 40 | 8 | 8 | Box 9 |
| E1 | V | 40 | 8 | 8 | Box 10 |

Note:

I want to distribute order qty into several box based on "Qty per Box" value in master category table.
For example :
On above data, I have order from N1 with P category and 40 Pcs quantity. I need to stored that order into the box based on Qty per box.
In that case, order N1 will be divided into 4 box with 12 Pcs quantity and 1 box with 4 pcs quantity. this last box will be available for storage for next customer N2 in this case until reach the max value of box.

I don't have any idea how to start with that, my brain was stuck.

Below is json data in php.
I think so, it's could complete with knapsack, but I cannot imagine how to do that, even I searching for that,
I use json format, below is data in php.
I think so, it's could complete with knapsack, but I cannot imagine how to do that, even I searching for that,
I use json format, below is data in php.

```
[[{"Customer":"N1","Category":"P","OrderQty":"41","MaxQtyBox":"12"},{"Customer":"N2","Category":"P","OrderQty":"8","MaxQtyBox":"12"},[{"Customer":"E1","Category":"V","OrderQty":"1","MaxQtyBox":"36"},{"Customer":"E1","Category":"V","OrderQty":"1","MaxQtyBox":"36"}]]
```

Comment: Please explain, in words, how it is that you get to that expected result. It's not clear just looking at the data.

Comment: Sorry for unclear questions,
I want to distribute order qty into several box based on "Qty per Box" value in master category table. 
For example : 
On above data, I have order from N1 with P category and 40 Pcs quantity. I need to stored that order into the box based on Qty per box.
In that case, order N1 will be divided into 4 box with 12 Pcs quantity and 1 box with 4 pcs quantity. this last box will be available for storage for next customer N2 in this case until reach the max value of box.

Comment: Oh! got it. Thus the "Knapsack".

Comment: Can you share example data in php format. Is this stuff in an array, json object? A starting point so folks here can toss it into their environment and code on top of it would be beneficial.

Comment: I think so, it's could complete with knapsack, but I cannot imagine how to do that, even I searching for that,
I use json format, below is data in php.

[[{"Customer":"N1","Category":"P","OrderQty":"41","MaxQtyBox":"12"},{"Customer":"N2","Category":"P","OrderQty":"8","MaxQtyBox":"12"},[{"Customer":"E1","Category":"V","OrderQty":"1","MaxQtyBox":"36"},{"Customer":"E1","Category":"V","OrderQty":"1","MaxQtyBox":"36"}]]

Comment: Please edit your question rather than adding details in comments.

Comment: Its already edited,